# NetSuite Email Subscription Preferences URL

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to implement Email Subscription Preferences Page in My Application.

I need its Page Parameters to integrate in our system.
Below is the Sample Page URL.

https://forms.na0.netsuite.com/app/crm/marketing/campaignlistener.nl?__lstr=__su&c=654321_SB1&__h=44cd99093432310c4d004&__e=150000

I write a Simple Code

```
 var context = nlapiGetContext();
 var bundleid = context.getBundleId();
 var user = context.getUser();  // It gives __e parameter.
```

**I need __h parameter ?** please let me know how I can fetch this parameter.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible. You'll need to hard-code complete URL in your system.